# legend chropleth map leaflet didn't show the getColor value

Tags: javascript, leaflet, choropleth

I've been trying to add a legend to my leaflet map. and im using this tutorial https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/
but the legend is not showing the corect value from getColor()
this is the legend showing in my project
[this is my project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycyzn.png)

ive been include the css and the getColor value.
this is the legend code

```
    var legend = L.control({
        position: 'bottomright'
    });

    legend.onAdd = function(map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 2.3, 2.4, 2.8],
            labels = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            from = grades[i];
            to = grades[i + 1];

            labels.push(
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
        }

        div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
        return div;
    };

    legend.addTo(map);
```

how to fix this  problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem are your small values [0, 2.3, 2.4, 2.8], and you are calling function getColor(from + 1). You can try change added value getColor(from + 0.01)